# Right-to-left alignment of PyQt4 menus

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, right-to-left

I use PyQt4 for designing GUI.

I want to know is there a way to sort menu items from right to left instead left to right for languages such as Arabic or Persian?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the `setLayoutDirection()` method of `QApplicacion` to indicate the `Qt.RightToLeft` address as shown below:

```
class menudemo(QMainWindow):
   def __init__(self, parent = None):
      super(menudemo, self).__init__(parent)

      layout = QHBoxLayout()
      bar = self.menuBar()
      file = bar.addMenu("ملف")
      file.addAction("الجديد")

      save = QAction("حفظ",self)
      file.addAction(save)

      edit = file.addMenu("تصحيح")
      edit.addAction("نسخ")
      edit.addAction("معجون")

      quit = QAction("استقال",self) 
      file.addAction(quit)
      file.triggered[QAction].connect(self.processtrigger)
      self.setLayout(layout)
      self.setWindowTitle("RTL")

   def processtrigger(self,q):
      print(q.text()+" is triggered")

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app = QApplication(sys.argv)
   app.setLayoutDirection(Qt.RightToLeft)
   ex = menudemo()
   ex.show()
   sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, a lot, awesome!